# Button Style: Transitioning from solid to gradient color without messing up the animation

Tags: css, animation, button, gradient

I got this code here and made some changes to mimic the button style and functions I like. However, I'm having a little trouble turning the single color into a gradient without messing up the animation. Can you help me with that?

[image]

```css
.button-file {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 46px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.button-file::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 50%, 50% 50%;
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#38718F, #38718F 0%), linear-gradient(#38718F, #38718F), linear-gradient(#D0555A, #D0555A), linear-gradient(#D0555A, #D0555A);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.button-file:hover::before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}

.button-file::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">

  <div class="button-file">
    <a><b>Contact us</b></b></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The code you've provided rotates the gradient, whereas the pictures you provide shows a gradient running from left to right. What are you trying to accomplish? Also, could you add the specific colours that you're trying to use in that gradient (you've shown quite a few in the CSS, but since that CSS doesn't appear to be working I don't want to use those necessarily).

Comment: I'd like to blend the two solid colors, just like in the picture I shared. 

#38718F and #D0555A

Comment: So, this: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hfvz9c5g/)?

Comment: You have two closing `</b>` Is that a typo?

Comment: Hi @DavidThomas , thanks for this, but this is what I am trying to accomplish that's why I'd like to blend the two colors https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/23983258?key=85e9fb0e7529cf8cc4a211085d00bf47

Comment: Hi @Rob yes that's typo, thank you for checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use the `@property` syntax to animate gradients and use those in the `transition` CSS property. Some information on CSS Tricks [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-property-for-css-custom-properties/)

Note: this doesn't work on Firefox at the moment but is included in version 124 which is just coming out so will have almost complete browser coverage.

Your button would look like this:

```css
/* set initial values */

@property --redpos{
  syntax: '<percentage>'; 
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 50%;
}

@property --bluepos{
  syntax: '<percentage>'; 
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 50%;
}

.button-file {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 46px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,  #38718F var(--redpos), #D0555A var(--bluepos));
  transition: --redpos 500ms, --bluepos 500ms;
}

/* on hover change the values */
.button-file:hover {
  --redpos:0%;
  --bluepos:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-file">
  <a><b>Contact us</b></a>
</div>
```

**Edited to add**
I've seen from an amendment from your initial answer that you want to rotate the background. The same principle applies, just change the angle of the linear-gradient as follows:

```css
@property --angle{
  syntax: '<angle>'; 
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 90deg;
}

.button-file {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 46px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  
  transition: --angle 500ms;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--angle),  #38718F, #D0555A);
}

.button-file:hover {
  --angle:270deg;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-file">
  <a><b>Contact us</b></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, but this is what I am trying to accomplish.

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/23983258?key=85e9fb0e7529cf8cc4a211085d00bf47

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include this solution

Comment: Thank you, Adam! Your help means a lot. I've been working on this animation for almost 3 days, and I appreciate your support. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Adam, the code didn't work here. Is there another way to fix this? Sorry, I'm new to web development. I'm currently using Elementor. https://paste.pics/4ecdd329029fe038cd7468c3bb9bdc8b

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry late reply, I was just on my day off. I used Google browser, and I used WordPress Elementor builder to create the website.